# How to select all inside node tag in XML via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

[Required Output - Green mark data i want in my sql dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsU0C.png)

Can anyone help me please?

I would like to select all the nodes in xml and get its Key-Value and Value in my dataset.

I have tried but I can only get specific tag result.

I have numeric-entity, list-entity and string-entity in my xml and I want to get values from each tag.

So far I can get only one entity value but I don't know how I can write OR condition or something in query to get result from all the xmls tag.

This is my xml and the query I have written:

```
--Query
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:guru.cincom.com-Hierarchy')
SELECT t.ID
    
      ,T0.Color.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS EntityName
      ,T0.Color.value('(key-value/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS EntityValue  
FROM ConfigurationDnaItem t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(t.Value AS XML)) As A(AllNodes)
CROSS APPLY A.AllNodes.nodes('/hierarchy/nodes/numeric-entity[not(values/value/key-value[text() = "N/A" or text() = "NA" or text() = "Nil"])]') AS T0(Color)
where t.id = 'BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67';
```

Xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsU0C.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<hierarchy name="DGTrailerDimensionH" xmlns="urn:guru.cincom.com-Hierarchy">
  <nodes>
    <numeric-entity name="UnitLength">
      <key-value>14500</key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[14500]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Overall Length]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </numeric-entity>
    <list-entity name="UnitHeightList">
      <values>
        <value>
          <key-value><![CDATA[4300]]></key-value>
          <characteristics>
            <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[4300]]></characteristic>
            <characteristic name="Description" type="string"><![CDATA[4300]]></characteristic>
            <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Overall Height]]></characteristic>
          </characteristics>
        </value>
      </values>
      <extended-properties />
    </list-entity>
    <numeric-entity name="CoamingHeight">
      <key-value>25</key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[25]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Coaming Height above main]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </numeric-entity>
    <list-entity name="TurntableHeightList">
      <values>
        <value>
          <key-value><![CDATA[1270]]></key-value>
          <characteristics>
            <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[1270]]></characteristic>
            <characteristic name="Description" type="string"><![CDATA[1270]]></characteristic>
            <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Skidplate Height]]></characteristic>
          </characteristics>
        </value>
      </values>
      <extended-properties />
    </list-entity>
    <numeric-entity name="ApertureHeight">
      <key-value>2725</key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[2725]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Aperture Height]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </numeric-entity>
    <numeric-entity name="ApertureLength">
      <key-value>14200</key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[14200]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Aperture Length]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </numeric-entity>
    <numeric-entity name="FifthWheelLocationNum">
      <key-value>0</key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[0]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Turntable Location]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </numeric-entity>
    <numeric-entity name="SuspensionLocation">
      <key-value>9350</key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[9350]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Suspension Location]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </numeric-entity>
    <numeric-entity name="SuspensionSpreadNum">
      <key-value>2700</key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[2700]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Suspension spread]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </numeric-entity>
    <string-entity name="KingPinLocationStr">
      <key-value><![CDATA[1550]]></key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[1550]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[King Pin Position]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </string-entity>
    <numeric-entity name="RearApertureHeight">
      <key-value>0</key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[0]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Rear Aperture Height]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </numeric-entity>
    <numeric-entity name="DropDeckHeightNum">
      <key-value>0</key-value>
      <characteristics>
        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[0]]></characteristic>
        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Drop Deck Height]]></characteristic>
      </characteristics>
      <extended-properties />
    </numeric-entity>
  </nodes>
</hierarchy>


  [1]: Out required - Green mark i want in data set.
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: I would like to get all  name="Value and name="DGName" in my dataset in sql. based on my sql query i can get on numeric-entity's name="Value and name="DGName" only but in xml there are different tags as well like string-entity and List-entity. I am not sure how i can add in my query. hope this will help to give me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution. It is following the same **minimal reproducible example** paradigm. You copy it to SSMS as-is, run it, and it is working.

Though I don't understand the XPath expression predicate:

```
[not(values/value/key-value[text() = ("N/A","NA","Nil")])]
```

Please clarify what you are trying to filter out.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY, [value] NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, value) VALUES
('BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67'
, N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<hierarchy name="DGTrailerDimensionH" xmlns="urn:guru.cincom.com-Hierarchy">
    <nodes>
        <numeric-entity name="UnitLength">
            <key-value>14500</key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[14500]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Overall Length]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </numeric-entity>
        <list-entity name="UnitHeightList">
            <values>
                <value>
                    <key-value><![CDATA[4300]]></key-value>
                    <characteristics>
                        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[4300]]></characteristic>
                        <characteristic name="Description" type="string"><![CDATA[4300]]></characteristic>
                        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Overall Height]]></characteristic>
                    </characteristics>
                </value>
            </values>
            <extended-properties/>
        </list-entity>
        <numeric-entity name="CoamingHeight">
            <key-value>25</key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[25]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Coaming Height above main]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </numeric-entity>
        <list-entity name="TurntableHeightList">
            <values>
                <value>
                    <key-value><![CDATA[1270]]></key-value>
                    <characteristics>
                        <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[1270]]></characteristic>
                        <characteristic name="Description" type="string"><![CDATA[1270]]></characteristic>
                        <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Skidplate Height]]></characteristic>
                    </characteristics>
                </value>
            </values>
            <extended-properties/>
        </list-entity>
        <numeric-entity name="ApertureHeight">
            <key-value>2725</key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[2725]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Aperture Height]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </numeric-entity>
        <numeric-entity name="ApertureLength">
            <key-value>14200</key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[14200]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Aperture Length]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </numeric-entity>
        <numeric-entity name="FifthWheelLocationNum">
            <key-value>0</key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[0]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Turntable Location]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </numeric-entity>
        <numeric-entity name="SuspensionLocation">
            <key-value>9350</key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[9350]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Suspension Location]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </numeric-entity>
        <numeric-entity name="SuspensionSpreadNum">
            <key-value>2700</key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[2700]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Suspension spread]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </numeric-entity>
        <string-entity name="KingPinLocationStr">
            <key-value><![CDATA[1550]]></key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[1550]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[King Pin Position]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </string-entity>
        <numeric-entity name="RearApertureHeight">
            <key-value>0</key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[0]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Rear Aperture Height]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </numeric-entity>
        <numeric-entity name="DropDeckHeightNum">
            <key-value>0</key-value>
            <characteristics>
                <characteristic name="Value" type="list"><![CDATA[0]]></characteristic>
                <characteristic name="DGName" type="string"><![CDATA[Drop Deck Height]]></characteristic>
            </characteristics>
            <extended-properties/>
        </numeric-entity>
    </nodes>
</hierarchy>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:guru.cincom.com-Hierarchy')
SELECT t.ID
    , p.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS EntityName
    , p.value('(.//key-value/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS EntityValue
    , c.value('(characteristic[@name="Value"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS char_Value
    , c.value('(characteristic[@name="DGName"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS char_GName
    , c.value('(characteristic[@name="Description"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS char_desc
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST(t.Value AS XML)) AS A(AllNodes)
CROSS APPLY A.AllNodes.nodes('/hierarchy/nodes/*[not(values/value/key-value[text() = ("N/A","NA","Nil")])]') AS t0(p)
CROSS APPLY t0.p.nodes('.//characteristics') AS t1(c)
WHERE t.id = 'BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67';
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|                  ID                  |      EntityName       | EntityValue | char_Value |        char_GName         | char_desc |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | UnitLength            |       14500 |      14500 | Overall Length            | NULL      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | UnitHeightList        |        4300 |       4300 | Overall Height            | 4300      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | CoamingHeight         |          25 |         25 | Coaming Height above main | NULL      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | TurntableHeightList   |        1270 |       1270 | Skidplate Height          | 1270      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | ApertureHeight        |        2725 |       2725 | Aperture Height           | NULL      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | ApertureLength        |       14200 |      14200 | Aperture Length           | NULL      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | FifthWheelLocationNum |           0 |          0 | Turntable Location        | NULL      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | SuspensionLocation    |        9350 |       9350 | Suspension Location       | NULL      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | SuspensionSpreadNum   |        2700 |       2700 | Suspension spread         | NULL      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | KingPinLocationStr    |        1550 |       1550 | King Pin Position         | NULL      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | RearApertureHeight    |           0 |          0 | Rear Aperture Height      | NULL      |
| BA84B6C7-B6F7-4FC9-9DD8-8C9022513A67 | DropDeckHeightNum     |           0 |          0 | Drop Deck Height          | NULL      |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Awesome, It worked. Thanks